# How can I update multiple device registrations on Azure notification hub

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api2, azure-notificationhub

Is there any way that I can update a tag or tags on multiple devices registrations on Azure notification hub in one method call by passing installationId of all the devices by using asp.net web api backend.

Lets say I have a tag "BreakingNews" and I want to update this tag on 1000 devices which are already registered on Azure notification hub, need to achieve this goal by using Asp.net Web Api backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`NotificationHubClient.GetRegistrationsByTagAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.azure.notificationhubs.notificationhubclient.getregistrationsbytagasync.aspx) to get all registrations with a specific tag and then iterate over them and update them one by one.

Or you can use [notification hub jobs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.azure.notificationhubs.notificationhubjob.aspx) to [export and modify registrations in bulk](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn790624.aspx) which requires an Azure Storage blob container.